# How to ride an escalator

Tags: words, nuances

I came across this phrase in a story book:

> エスカレーターを乗りつぐ

It puzzled me because I thought 乗りつぐ meant 'to connect with (flight/train etc)'. Is this the normal way to talk about getting on/riding an escalator? If not, what nuance does it convey and what would be a more typical verb to use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

People usually say エスカレーターに乗る, エスカレーターで8階まで上がる, etc.

エスカレーターを乗り継ぐ is not common, but it would be accepted if one wants to explicitly say (for whatever reason) riding several escalators in succession.

> エスカレーターを乗り継いで1階から8階まで上がる
>   (cf. 電車を乗り継いで東京から九州まで行く)

Comment: 時々1階から2階だけは真ん中にエスカレーターがあってその上はフロアの端にあるようなお店とかありますね…